# How do I get the active route pathname in react-router 1?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a route defined like:

```
<Route path='/invite(/:inviteToken)' component={InvitePage}
                key='/invite(/:inviteToken)' onEnter={requireAdmin} />
```

and the current URL is

```
/invite/abc123
```

In my code, how do I get the current Route, so that I can get the path/key? (I need that as an index into another array)

Answer (score 1):

From the docs: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/Introduction.md#adding-more-ui

```
<Route path="messages/:id" component={Message} />
```

Now visits to URLs like inbox/messages/Jkei3c32 will match the new route and build this for you:

```
<Message params={{ id: 'Jkei3c32' }}/>
```

So in your case, you would use `this.props.params.inviteToken` in the `InvitePage` component.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. Perhaps this is closer to what you needed? https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/guides/advanced/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md You should be able to get current path from the `browserHistory` object.

Comment: Or maybe `this.context.router.getCurrentRoutes()`

Comment: `this.context.router` doesn't seem to be available in v1.0

Answer (score 0):

In your `InvitePage` component, it should be available under `this.props.params.inviteToken`.

Comment: I am really after the Route, so I can get the key or path from that. The params, I am able to grab already.